# Ensure S3 methods from dependent package are loaded when using double colon (::)

Tags: r, mschart, officer

When using S3 methods from dependent packages, how do I ensure that a package loads (and attaches?) all dependent packages when called using the double colon (::) operator without a prior `library()` call?

I am developing a package `package3` that uses `package1` and `package2`. `package1` defines an S3 method `funky` and `package2` defines methods for additional types. If I use the `funky` method in my own package, `package3`, then R cannot find the relevant S3 method, even though `package3` imports both `package1` and `package2`.

The actual problems occurs with the officer and mschart project, but it is generic and I have created a reusable example using 3 separate packages in RStudio

**Context**

`package1`
Defines `funky(arg)` and `funky.character(arg)`. Both methods are exported

`package2`
Defines `funky.numeric(arg)`. Imports `package1` *However, Roxygen does not generate a `S3method` in NAMESPACE*

`package3`
Defines `hello()` which calls `funky(100)` (i.e the numeric method should be called). Imports `package1` and `package2` (I've also tried with depends),

**Reproduce the problem**

`package3::hello()` generates an error regarding the missing S3 method

**Workaround**

```
library(package3)
package3::hello()
```

However, because the package will be used internally within our company I can't expect everyone to know that `library()` has to be called first

Any ideas on how I can ensure that all relevant S3 methods are available even when using the double colon (::) operator?

Many thanks in advance

Jonas

Answer (score 1):

You could add the line

```
Depends: package2
```

To the DESCRIPTION file in your package's root directory. This ensures that anyone who installs your package will automatically install `package2`. It also makes sure that `package2` is loaded and on the users' search path any time your package is loaded.

Another possibility would be to add

```r
#' @export
funky.numeric <- package2:::funky.numeric
```

Near the top of your main R file. This should work in practice if this is a package just for use within your own company, though it wouldn't be allowed on CRAN. This should allow users to do `package1::funky(x)` with appropriate dispatch.

Comment: Hi Allan, Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately the Depends does not address the issue as the package is still not attached when invoking the function using the double colon (::) operator

Regarding the workaround indeed I can call the specific function but then some of the purpose of the S3 function is lost. In the minimal example I could call it but in practice I do not know the exact type when calling the S3 method.

Comment: @Jonas but why not have all the relevant S3 methods exported from your package like above? It's only a single line per class. Remember, you are asking "how do I get my package to select an unexported method from a different package without loading or attaching that different package?". The answer surely has to involve copying the method from the other package or forcing it to be loaded. You have to access the code _somehow_.